# Eclipse not correctly indenting HTML in PHP files (PDT)

Tags: php, html, eclipse, formatting

I'm using PDT in Eclipse Luna, and whenever I format a PHP file, it doesn't format the html inside correctly. This is how it looks:

```
<?php http_response_code(404);  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <?php
        $headTemplate = new Template('head');
        $headTemplate->display(array(
                'title' => 'File not found (404)'
        ));
        ?>
    </head>
<body>
        <?php
        $headerTemplate = new Template('header');
        $headerTemplate->display();
        ?>
        <div class="page_header">
        <div class="margins_menu2">
            <h1 class="color_stylishred">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>File not found (404)
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="margins_page">The file you requested could not be found.</div>
    </div>
        <?php
        $footerTemplate = new Template('footer');
        $footerTemplate->display();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the head and body tags aren't indented correctly. Where and how can I change this? There is no option for HTML formatting in the preferences. Thanks!

As a bonus question, is there a way to make eclipse indent the code between `<?php` and `?>` tags?

Comment: You should report a but on PDT bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT

Comment: @zulus So it is a bug then? I though it might be related to the default settings. I'll make a new bug report.

Comment: Eclipse Mars still formats HTML improperly (that's why I'm here; first search result), with no option to change it. Zend Studio however does let you change it, though not by enough. I've found better luck with PHPStorm, but even that is limited in proper formatting and config, so I try different online formatters, and jsbeautify is my favorite.